# monerod v0.12.0.0 can't synchronize

Tags: monerod, synchronization

I'm on Version 0.12.0.0

`2018-05-10 08:03:53.066 [P2P6]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:1464 ###### REORGANIZE on height: 1568536 of 1568547 with cum_difficulty 14490123635886036
 alternative blockchain size: 13 with cum_difficulty 14490179675843288
2018-05-10 08:04:38.570 [P2P6]  ERROR   blockchain      src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:886  Failed to switch to alternative blockchain`

Answer (score 1):

These were likely bugs which are fixed on the current release-0.12 branch.
There should be a new 0.12.1.0 release in the next few days to a week, which will include these fixes.

See these:

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3719
https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3776
https://github.com/monero-project/monero/pull/3788

Answer (score 0):

I synchonized a few mins ago with ./monerod --db-sync-mode=fast --fast-block-sync=1. 
[73.162.222.49:18080 OUT]  Synced 1569721/1569721
Try start with clear database(--data-dir="your_new_dir") or --offline to determine where the trouble(database or net connection)

Answer (score -1):

In my case helped:
monero-blockchain-import --pop-blocks 2000
then
monerod --block-sync-size 1